# str.replace not working on my series - but works well on example

Tags: python, dataframe, str-replace

In my dataframe, I have a variable that should be a number, but is currently recognized as a string, with space after the thousand's value, for example : "5 948.5"

Before I can convert it to a float, I need to remove that space

```py
d = {'col1': [1,2], 'numbers': [' 4 856.4','5 000.5']}
data = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

data['numbers']=data['numbers'].str.replace(" ", "")
```

This works perfectly.

But when I do the exact same thing to my series, nothing happens (no error message, but the spaces remain). Other manipulations to that series work normally.

Any idea of what I can try to understand and fix the problem on my series? 
Thanks!

Edit: 
I ve loaded the data with a

```py
pd.read_csv(file.csv, encoding = "ISO-8859-1")
```

could that be responsible for the unmovable spaces?  If I did not do that, I'd have an error message when loading "UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe8 in position 2: invalid continuation byte"
I have tried to call read_csv with encoding='latin1', and encoding='cp1252' - the problem remains.

Edit 1.b. it seems to be an issue with the encoding of the space (Thanks @Marat). I downloaded an excel version of the data, and tried to replace all spaces of that column by nothing. It did not work. Removing a few spaces manually did work (but the file is too large to do it this way)

Edit 2: sample data. It really looks like the example I gave above, that works..but it really doesnt. I know nobody can reproduce this on their computer, I am not asking for the solution, but rather for ideas of what could be wrong...

As requested: here is a copytoclipboard of my data:

```py
GroupeRA,SecteurMA,StatutMA,TypeMA,fields_ancienMatricule,historizedFields_denomination,Annee,region,fields_codeComiteSubregional,arrondissement,fields_ins,adresse_commune,perequation

Crèches,MASS,Collectif,CREC,632100101,Le Bocage I,2017,RBC,BX,Bruxelles-capitale,21001,Anderlecht,"0,00 "
Crèches,MASS,Collectif,CREC,632100101,Le Bocage I,2018,RBC,BX,Bruxelles-capitale,21001,Anderlecht,"0,00 "
Crèches,MASS,Collectif,CREC,x,Le xyzI,2018,RBC,BX,Bruxelles-capitale,21001,Anderlecht,"1 302,26 "
Crèches,MASS,Collectif,CREC,632100101,Le Bocage I,2018,RBC,BX,Bruxelles-capitale,21001,Anderlecht,"687,56 "
Crèches,MASS,Collectif,CREC,632100101,xyz,2019,RBC,BX,Bruxelles-capitale,21001,Anderlecht,"1 372,91 "
```

Edit 3: the data is in csv (though as mentioned in edit 1.b I also got the data in xls and have the same issue (even when opening in xls directly, cannot "find&replace all" to find the spaces, as if excel did not read them as such) 
I used DB vizualizer to extract the data from our database.

Comment: Hmmm... You've shown something that works and ask why someting you haven't shown does not work. That's difficult to answer ;)

Comment: Hello could you provide a sample of your data or sample code? Normaly your solution should work.

Comment: It's not normal to not work with your code, try this,```df.perequation = df.perequation.str.replace(' ', '')```

Comment: unicode has plenty of other space symbols. I would check if the space you're trying to replace is actually the ASCII space

Comment: @Marat thanks - can you point me towards how to check this?

Comment: Using your data, `df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', thousands=' ', decimal=',')` worked for me  `perequation                      5 non-null float64`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for your help. It was indeed an issue with the "space" character - which was not a 'space' like the one produced by my keyboard. Got solved with the following sql command when extracting the data

[perequation]= CONVERT(MONEY,REPLACE(REPLACE(ds.computedFields_perequation, CHAR(160),''), ',', '.')),